# How to remove NA and move the non-NA values to new column?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

After spread function I would like to copy non-NA values to new column. 
Is there any way to let data that is not NA be copied to new columns?

**Data**

```
Serial_ID   Repair_type    Col1        Col2         Coln+1
ID_1            Warranty    NA         02.02.2013   NA
ID_1            Normal      NA         15.10.2011   12.01.2012
ID_2            Warranty    01-01-2013 NA           NA
ID_2            Normal      NA         NA           18.12.2014
ID_n            Normal      NA         23.01.2014   NA
```

**Desired result**

```
Serial_ID   Repair_type    ColX (new)  ColX2 (new)   Col1      Col2         
ID_1            Warranty   02.02.2013 
ID_1            Normal     15.10.2011  12.01.2012
ID_2            Warranty   01-01-2013 
ID_2            Normal     18.12.2014
ID_n            Normal     23.01.2014
```

Please see the data and result on image below:

[image]

Hope that makes it clearer. Thank you in advance.

---

**Long data before spread**

Data:

```
COMM_VIN    Si_DocDate  COMM_Kind   Cost
V1  2017-01-01  Normal  100
V1  2017-03-02  Warranty    200
V2  2015-04-04  Warranty    50
V2  2017-05-22  Warranty    100
V3  2004-05-22  Normal  150
V3  2016-06-01  Normal  250
```

I would like the dates of visits to the site to be moved to the column for the COMM_VIN variable depending on COMM_Kind

**Results:**

```
COMM_VIN    COMM_Kind   Col_ne1 Col_nen Cost(sum)
V1  Normal  2017-01-01      100
V1  Warramty    2015-04-04  2017-03-02  250
V2  Normal  2004-05-22  2016-06-01  400
V2  Warranty    2017-05-22      50
```

Sorry, I don't know how to add the table.
Please see the attached picture:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Peter, if you post your original data can give an a go at providing an answer. You can use `dput(head(df, 20))` to provide a sample of it. In general using pictures of your data isn't the best at it makes it hard to reproduce then. See here for some info on asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To add to NColl's comment, there is a FAQ just about r. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This is probably more easily dealt with *before* the `spread`... Can you share the long data?

Comment: Hi @iod, the post has been edited with previous data set (before spread).

Comment: Ummm.. There's no key column. How did you spread it?

Comment: @iod did you see the edited post. Maybe there is a better way to spread those data set? Do you have any idea? I've tried to spread by additional index column [1..n]. That is the reason of a lot of NA columns and rows.

Comment: I revised my solution to fit your long data. Also, to add tables in a formatted manner, add four spaces in the beginning of every line, or, more easily, select the table after you pasted it and click on the curly-brackets icon in the icons bar on top of the text box.

Comment: Dear @iod. I've tried to use your code, but there is an error Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: Do you have dplyr and tidyr loaded? It sounds like it's using the wrong function, probably because you loaded plyr after dplyr. Try the code as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually easier to do from the long data, before you spread it:

```
dd %>% gather("key","value",-Serial_ID, -Repair_type) %>% 
 filter(!is.na(value)) %>% # reverse engineer original data (if the original had NAs, you'll need this row to remove them)
group_by(Serial_ID, Repair_type) %>% 
mutate(key=paste0("colx",row_number())) %>% # replace key with minimal number of keys
spread(key,value) # spread again
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Serial_ID, Repair_type [5]
  Serial_ID Repair_type colx1       colx2      
  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>      <chr>     
1 ID_1      Normal      15.10.2011 12.01.2012
2 ID_1      Warranty    02.02.2013 NA        
3 ID_2      Normal      18.12.2014 NA        
4 ID_2      Warranty    01-01-2013 NA        
5 ID_n      Normal      23.01.2014 NA
```

If you would REALLY want to avoid all NAs, even if at the end of a row, you'll need to replace the NAs with empty strings. But I would advise against that.

Here's the same solution applied to the long data you provided:

```
dd %>% group_by(COMM_VIN,COMM_Kind) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(Cost=sum(Cost),key=paste0("colx",row_number())) %>% 
    spread(key,Si_DocDate)
```

You'll note that I create the new cost sum column before the spread, to avoid creating multiple rows with the same COMM_VIN/Comm_Kind combination.

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   COMM_VIN, COMM_Kind [4]
  COMM_VIN COMM_Kind  Cost colx1      colx2     
  <fct>    <fct>     <int> <fct>      <fct>     
1 V1       Normal      100 2017-01-01 NA        
2 V1       Warranty    200 2017-03-02 NA        
3 V2       Warranty    150 2015-04-04 2017-05-22
4 V3       Normal      400 2004-05-22 2016-06-01
```

Comment: Thank you for your suport. Could you explain which column shoud I put into key and value?

Comment: Key is the column that will become the headers for the spreaded columns. Value is the values in this columns.

Comment: See revised solution above.

Comment: Dear @iod. Now it's work perfectly ;) Thank you for your suport.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `coalesce()` function from the `dplyr` package. I couldn't read in your data, but here's an example with dummy data:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(
  c1 = c(NA, "hey", NA),
  c2 = c(NA, NA, "ho"),
  c3 = c("go", NA, NA)
)

df %>% mutate(colx = coalesce(c1, c2, c3))
```

Produces:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  c1    c2    c3    colx 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 NA    NA    go    go   
2 hey   NA    NA    hey  
3 NA    ho    NA    ho
```

Comment: Some of OP's rows have more than one non-NA columns, so this won't do -- see the desired output.

Comment: @Nick DiQuattro  what if I do not know how many loudspeakers are to be created? (depends on the date set)